# FLASK API: TypeError: Object of type coroutine is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, flask

The function get_user_id_by_api_key works fine, as far as I understand the issue is in require_api_key_from_db. I've tried a lot of things, how can I make it work properly? Perhaps a problem with the database?

```
from flask import Flask, request
from functools import wraps
import asyncio
from flask import jsonify

from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
from database import DataBase

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

database = DataBase()

data_storage = {}

def require_api_key_from_db(func):
    @wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        api_key = request.headers.get("X-API-Key")
        if api_key:
            print(api_key)
            user_id = await database.get_user_id_by_api_key(api_key)
            print(user_id)
            if user_id is None:
                return {"error": "Unauthorized 2"}, 401
            else:
                print(user_id)
                kwargs["user_id"] = user_id
                result = await func(*args, **kwargs)
                return result
        return {"error": "Unauthorized"}, 401

    return wrapper

class DataResource(Resource):
    method_decorators = [require_api_key_from_db]

    def get(self, key):
        if key in data_storage:
            return {key: data_storage[key]}
        else:
            return {"error": "Not Found"}, 404

    def put(self, key):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument("value", type=str, required=True, help="Value cannot be blank.")
        args = parser.parse_args()

        data_storage[key] = args["value"]
        return {key: data_storage[key]}

    def delete(self, key):
        if key in data_storage:
            del data_storage[key]
            return {"result": "Deleted successfully"}
        else:
            return {"error": "Not Found"}, 404

api.add_resource(DataResource, "/data/<string:key>")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The function get_user_id_by_api_key works fine, as far as I understand the issue is in require_api_key_from_db. I've tried a lot of things, how can I make it work properly? Perhaps a problem with the database?Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your function `require_api_key_from_db` is returning a coroutine as `wrapper` is an async function. I'm unsure where you're calling it but it'll have to be awaited eventually. Perhaps you could do something along the lines of

```
def require_api_key_from_db(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        ...
        return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(f(*args, **kwargs))
    return wrapper
```

to sync